# Binding SelectedItems to a ObservableCollection property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

Why the `SelectedItems` can't be bound from XAML ?!..how can I bind it keeping MVVM pattern applied ?

Comment: You should provide some simplified sample code for reference. Without some context, we cannot provide any solutions.

Comment: Please provide some sample code, to give us better idea of your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind to SelectedItems from DataGrid or ListBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880589/bind-to-selecteditems-from-datagrid-or-listbox-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedItems` is a read only property it can't be bound to. Although there exist [ways around this with attached properties](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html)

Answer (score 0):

[`SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditems%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is read-only if you are trying to assign in.

If you are trying to read it, [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) has a handy [`EventToCommand`](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/05/19/handling-datagrid.selecteditems-in-an-mvvm-friendly-manner.aspx) to relay the `SelectedItems` to your `ViewModel`