# MVVM DataGrid SelectedItems can't bind

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I have Silverlight MVVM project and can't get DataGrid SelectedItems from XAML code in ViewModel...

```
<gps:DataGrid
            ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}"

            SelectedItems="{Binding Node, Mode=TwoWay}"

            Grid.Row="2"
            HeadersVisibility="None"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <gps:DataGrid.Columns>
               ...
            </gps:DataGrid.Columns>
        </gps:DataGrid>
```

I get an error `"The property "SelectedItems" does not have an accessible setter"`
How can I get this property in ViewModel?

Comment: I think, that would be **SelectedItem="{Binding Node, Mode=TwoWay}"** . Terms like _SelectedItems_  or (plurals of single selection) are generally a read only collection of one or more selectedItems.

Comment: yeah, but I want to get multiple selected items, not only one selected item... I want to get only, don't need to set value from viewmodel

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Binding SelectedItems in MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868445/wpf-binding-selecteditems-in-mvvm)

Comment: @BurnOut, Nahum answer will best suit your requirement in that case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind to SelectedItems from DataGrid or ListBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880589/bind-to-selecteditems-from-datagrid-or-listbox-in-mvvm)