# How to get selected items in wpf datagrid using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to get some selected rows items & try to manipulate them. Currently **SelectedItem** is giving me only one row at a time. And **SelectedItems** is not a dependency property. I found a solution by creating our own dependency property to get selected items. Is there any option apart from this?

Comment: I think answer for your question is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868445/wpf-binding-selecteditems-in-mvvm

Comment: SelectedItems is a **readonly** dependency property, which is the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind to SelectedItems from DataGrid or ListBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880589/bind-to-selecteditems-from-datagrid-or-listbox-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another possible solution is to add an IsSelected property onto the items your showing in your grid

```
public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
           RaisePropertyChanged(_isSelected, value);
        }
    }
```

and to then add a style onto the data grid row to change that property.

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" >
     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
  </Style>
```

Then to get the currently selected items:

```
  var selectedItems = Items.Where(i => i.IsSelected).ToList();
```