# How to get value of multiple selected rows of the Datagrid in C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am pretty new to C# MVVM, WPF . I have a DataGrid in which I can select Multiple Rows, I wanted to get the value of multiple rows as an Array of Objects.
I have seen the links like this but could not find what I want Exactly.

```
enter code here
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionUnit="FullRow"  BorderThickness="1" x:Name="ssa" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Items,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" GridLinesVisibility="All"   
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionMode="Single" Height="280" Width="1600" SelectedItem="{Binding selected_row}">

                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Get item" Command="{Binding get_item}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}">
                        </MenuItem>
```

```
            <DataGrid.Columns>


                <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" x:Name="item_name"  Binding="{Binding name,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Viewmodel.cs
binding for the datagrid item is given:
 private string Name;

```
    public string name
    {
        get { return Name; }
        set { Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("name"); }
    }
```

`enter code here`

for the selected item also binding is given, but I am not getting How to get value multiple selected rows of data grid as an Array of Objects

Comment: bind `SelectedItems` to an observable collection

Comment: @Bizhan SelectedItems does not have a public  setter. cannot be bound.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind to SelectedItems from DataGrid or ListBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880589/bind-to-selecteditems-from-datagrid-or-listbox-in-mvvm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the `SelectionChanged` event in an attached behaviour and the objects to the source collection yourself in the event handler. Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/01/30/wpf-using-behaviours-to-bind-to-readonly-properties-in-mvvm/) blog post for an example of how to use behaviours to bind to read-only properties in MVVM.

Your behaviour could be implemented something like this:

```
public class DataGridSelectedItemsBlendBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(object),
        typeof(DataGridSelectedItemsBlendBehavior ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null) { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });

    public IList SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
            this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var selectedItem in e.AddedItems)
                if (!SelectedItems.Contains(selectedItem))
                    SelectedItems.Add(selectedItem);

            foreach (var unselectedItem in e.RemovedItems)
                SelectedItems.Remove(unselectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```