# ListBox display multiple selected items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have here a `ListBox` which shall show serveral items where some of them are selected.

```
<ListBox IsEnabled="False" x:Name="SecondaryModelSelector" SelectionMode="Extended"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedSecondaryModels, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}, Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AvailableModels, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContentControl}}" >
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The selected items are set in a `ComboBox` and thus the `ListBox` is disabled and `Mode=OneWay` to disable selection in the `ListBox` itself.
The Template looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
 <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"  Value="true" />
 <Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Border x:Name="Border"  Padding="2">
     <ContentPresenter />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
     </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyListBoxBorder" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
 <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyListBoxItem}"/>
 <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
     <Border x:Name="OuterBorder">
      <ScrollViewer Margin="0"  Focusable="false">
       <StackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
   </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is now, that I cannot display multiple selected items, i.e. the background does not turn blue. Showing only one selected item is no problem.

Works (but shows only one selected item...)

```
public Cpu SelectedSecondaryModels
{
    get  { return SelectedGlobalVariable.SecondaryModels.FirstOrDefault();  }
}
```

Does not work:

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> SelectedSecondaryModels
{
    get  { return new ObservableCollection<Model>(SelectedGlobalVariable.SecondaryModels);  }
}
```

I have no errors, so how can I show multiple selected items?
I tried `SelectedItems` instead of `SelectedItem` instead, but this is read-only field.
When I allow to select items in the `ListBox` than the blue background appears, and binding throws errors as there is no setter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` property cannot be bound to a collection of several items to be selected.

And as you have already noticed, `SelectedItems` is a read-only property.

You could use an attached behaviour to work around this. Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/01/30/wpf-using-behaviours-to-bind-to-readonly-properties-in-mvvm/) and [this example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5041c158-e48b-4efd-9f73-848a85abba83/datagrid-selecteditems-in-mvvm?forum=wpf) for more information about how to do this.

You will also find some solutions here:

[Bind to SelectedItems from DataGrid or ListBox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880589/bind-to-selecteditems-from-datagrid-or-listbox-in-mvvm)

Comment: I hoped to find a better solution, as these links are already more or less several years old. Highly disappointing that there is no improvement...